# I can't delete NDNS interface in network preferences on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, mac, network, monterey

I uninstalled that profile but my network hasn't been deleted. I use the terminal to search using -listallnetworkservices to delete it but can't find it What should I do?

[image: System Perfrence]
[image: Network Perfrence]

Comment: Are you on Location "Automatic"? If you create a new location does the interface show up there as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating a New location but NDNS is still the same.